# How to find both a value that exists and doesn't exist in two tables through an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

So I have two tables. Table1 has a list of ID's and names. Table2 has a list of ID's referenced against ID's from another table. I want to find all the values where the other id is equal to 201 but also where ID's from table1 don't exist in table2. (or put another way, if an ID exists in table1 and is also in table2 but isn't associated with the otherID 201, I don't want it, but I do also want the ID's that aren't in table2 or 5 from table1)

So far I have:

```
SELECT table1.thisID, table1.thisName
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table2.otherID=201 AND table2ID.thisID=table1ID.thisID
AND table1.thisID NOT IN (table2.thisID)
```

The last line doesn't seem to do the trick. Suggestions helpful.
Thanks.

EDIT:

What i'm after is values in Table1 where either the ID is 5 or simply is non existant in table2.

Sample Data:

```
table1-
thisID         thisName
1               name1
2               name2
3               name3
4               name4
5               name5

table2-
otherID          thisID
201              5
209              3
210              2
```

So what I'm looking for it to return from table1 is thisID 1,4,5 and the corresponding names. Since 3 and 2 already exist in table2 and are not 5. Hope that makes more sense.

The desired result would be :

```
thisID         thisName
1                name1
4                name4
5                name5
```

because 1 and 4 don't exist in table2, but 5 correlates to 201.

Maybe in an more litteral sense:

```
WHERE table2.otherID=201 
AND table2.thisID=table1.thisID 
BUT ALSO IF table1.thisID DOES NOT EXIST IN table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Intersect and Except. You can learn more about these T-SQL functions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx).

Intersect will find all matching rows in two tables/queries (left and right input queries). Except will find all rows in the first query/table (left) that don't exist in the second query/table (right)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then this should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.ID = 5
OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2
              WHERE ID = t1.ID)
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25ae59/1) with a demo.

Comment: But this does not return the one with the value of 5. It just returns the ones that have not yet been asigned in table2.

Comment: @user3809554 Why not?, it has  `t1.ID = 5`. This seems to be exactly what you want

Comment: I've just run it. And it doesn't return that value. I've no idea why.

Comment: @user3809554 Then please post some sample data here, because it doesn't make sense

Comment: @user3809554 here is a [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25ae59/1) with my query showing that it works as intended

Comment: but the value 5 is not in your table2?

Comment: @user3809554 Look, clearly I'm not following your desired result. Using your sample data, [this are](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2af2f/1) the results I get, which I believe it's what you wanted

Comment: You're absolutely right. And thats because I screwed it up. What it should have been was table2.otherID=201 (aka it correlates to 5). Sorry about that.

Comment: @user3809554 Ok, so, is the answer giving you what you wanted?

Comment: Unfortunatly not. Because to achieve what I'm after, I'm pretty sure you have to join the tables since 'otherID' '201' is unique to table2.

Comment: @user3809554 Well, I don't know what you are after, really. Please, please, post your desired result for your sample data

Comment: I've updated the question it might hopefully make a little more sense now. I hope. Thanks for all the helping so far.

Comment: @user3809554 Sorry, I think I can't really help you anymore. You show that you wanted the results `1,4,5` and that's exactly what [**my answer**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2af2f/1) gives you

Comment: Yeah I realise that, but it's not gonna work for other values. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

SELECT table1.thisID, table1.thisName
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table2ID.thisID=table1ID.thisID 
WHERE table2ID.ThisID=5 OR table2ID.ThisID IS NULL

Answer (score -1):

Your last line should have been like this:

```
SELECT table1.thisID, table1.thisName
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table2.thisID=5 AND table2ID.thisID=table1ID.thisID
AND table1.thisID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT thisID FROM table2)
```